# Avoid Unix PATH duplicating with "set -f"

Tags: unix, path, set

I've seen a script that modifies the Unix $PATH, and in order to avoid duplicating items, it uses the following technic:

```
set path = ($path:q /some/new/path)
set path = ($path:q /another/directory)
set -f path = ($path:q)
```

I don't understand how is working...

Documentation to the "-f" flag says :

> Disable file name generation

which doesn't make any sense to me. And what's this strange ":q"?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

This [Super User Question](https://superuser.com/questions/234497/c-shell-environment-variable-error-bad-modifier-in) helped me understand that ":q" is a modifier.
And *tcsh man* explains it:

> When the `:q' modifier is applied to
>          a substitution the variable will expand to multiple  words
>          with  each word separated by a blank and quoted to prevent
>          later command or filename substitution

**Second Edit:**

Actually, it seems that "-f" alone does the magic:

```
~$ set days = (Sunday Monday Tuesday Monday Sunday)
~$ echo $days
Sunday Monday Tuesday Monday Sunday
~$ set -f days = ($days)
~$ echo $days
Sunday Monday Tuesday
```

Still, I don't understand how is result of "Disable file name generation".

Comment: It must be `PATH` your are talking of and not `path`. Unix is case-sensitive.

Comment: I know. It's indeed strange. I'm working in a new job, and I saw here this script. Maybe there is something else I don't understand here?

Comment: Actually, my question is for all environment variables. PATH (or the strange 'path') are just interesting use cases.

Comment: In `tcsh`, `$path` is space-separated wordlist and `$PATH` is colon-separated string.  The two are automatically kept in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling file name generation usually needed if we encounter file names that contain `*`, `?`, `{}` etc. Care should be taken while handling these files so that we don't process file name as a wildcard pattern. Crete a file named stack* as `vim stack*`, later we shouldn't delete this file since all other files start with `stack` also gets deleted. Alternate way to delete the file is using quoting as `rm "stack*"`. If required it is possible to enable file name generation by `set +f` in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion arises from the fact that you're reading the `ksh` manual, but you're using the `tcsh` shell.  `Tcsh` syntax is very different from the vastly more common POSIX shell syntax.

The command `set` is built-in to the shell, so when you run `set` in `tcsh` you get an entirely different command to `set` run from `ksh`.

From [`man tcsh`](http://man.cx/tcsh%281%29):

> ```
>    set [-r] [-f|-l] name=(wordlist) ... (+)
>            ...
>            If -f or -l are specified,  set only unique words keeping their
>            order.   -f  prefers the first occurrence of a word, and -l the
>            last.
> ```